# How can I prevent an Scala function to receive 'null' as an argument

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I've got a Scala method with this signature:

```
  def m (map: Map [String, _])
```

I suppose Map is a reference type and as such, I can call `m` passing `null`

```
  m (null) // Allowed call
```

Is there any way for the compiler to do not allow `null` is some method calls? Other languages like Kotlin allow this by explicitly saying that a parameter can be null: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Is there anything like that in Scala?

EDIT: Thank you for your comments. I understand that 'null' references are a runtime matter, but other languages with other type systems take care of this at compile time.

I only wanted to know if there was a way in Scala too (I'm starting to use the language). Checking the comments, the answer, and the [Scala type hierachy](http://lmazy.verrech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/scala_type_hierarchy.png) I guest this is not possible.

For value objects (like immutable collections and case classes) it could make sense to avoid 'null' (however they extend `AnyRef`).

I could try to avoid 'null', but for example Map.get returns 'null' if the key is not found, so I have to handle this.

Regarding the `Map[String, _]` it is a heterogenous map, think of it as a JSON object. May I handle this in a different, more Scala-like way?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible with the standard compiler, and not really working with compiler plugin. The marker trait `NotNull` has been deprecated since 2.11. Btw working with `_` as type of map value is not helping type safety.

Comment: `null` exists in Scala for the purpose of Java interop. We generally pretend it doesn't exist, because it's fundamentally broken. Just never pass `null` anywhere ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any reference type (`AnyRef`) can, by definition of the JVM, be `null`, and the compiler cannot enforce that no client side calls your function with `null`.

I highly recommend not using `null` values at all when working with Scala. If you need to handle absent values, use the `Option` type instead.